# Change field to timestamp

Tags: logstash

I have a csv file which store up cpu usage. There is a field with date format like this "20150101-00:15:00". How can I change it to @timestamp in logstash as shown in kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date filter on that field:

```
date {
     match => [ "dateField" , "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss"]
}
```

It will add the @timestamp field.
See documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html

Comment: And one concern is that the timestamp seems to be automated as +0 timezone but not local timezone as +8hr

Comment: Using the theory similar and I have get reference online, why I could not map the timestamp 'Sep 19, 2015 10:16:36 PM HKT' as 'MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss aa zzz'. It gives me error like this --> [33mFailed parsing date from field {:field=>"Date", :value=>"Sep 19, 2015 10:16:36 PM HKT", :exception=>"Invalid format
: \"Sep 19, 2015 10:16:36 PM HKT\" is malformed at \" 19, 2015 10:16:36 PM HKT\"", :config_parsers=>"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:
ss aa Z,MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss aa Z", :config_locale=>"default=en_US", :level=>:warn}←[0m